# Is a position vector with an argument or not? $\mathbf{r}$ vs $\mathbf{r}(t)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I thought a position vector was a vector without an argument: $$
\mathbf{r}=(x,y,z)=x\mathbf{\hat e}_x+y\mathbf{\hat e}_y+z\mathbf{\hat e}_z$$
So for a vector field $\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r})=\mathbf{E}(x,y,z)$.

However, wikipedia [define a position vector with an argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position_(vector)#Three_dimensions), a vector function:
$$
\mathbf{r}(t)=(x(t),y(t),z(t))=x(t)\mathbf{\hat e}_x+y(t)\mathbf{\hat e}_y+z(t)\mathbf{\hat e}_z$$
But then a vector field is $\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r}(t))=\mathbf{E}(x(t),y(t),z(t))$?

Which is correct? And which is correct as an argument for a vector field?

EDIT: I didn't mean $t$ necessarily is the time, $t$ just could be any variable of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

Well the answer is whether it's time dependent or not? If it is, there's an argument $t$ if it isn't there isn't.

For example supposing you solved $F(\mathbf{r})=m\ddot{\mathbf{r}}$.
Then generally $r$ will depend on $t$ as the particle traces out the curve of its motion in a force field $F$. I've hidden the implicit $t$. There is of course the special case where $\mathrm{r}$ is constant in time.

Now $F$ is vector field and in this case we could have $F(t,\mathbf{r}(t),\dot{\mathbf{r}}(t), \ldots)$ .

Comment: Thanks! So it depends on context? Often books just use $\mathbf{F}$ without any argument. E.g. [law of gravitation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_universal_gravitation#Vector_form) is without an argument, just $\mathbf{F}$. However on the same page the [gravitational field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_universal_gravitation#Gravitational_field) is listed with an argument. Should I interpret $\mathbf{F}_{12}$ as $\mathbf{F}_{12}(\mathbf{r}(t))$ or as $\mathbf{F}_{12}(\mathbf{r})$? And also $\mathbf{g}(\mathbf{r})$ or $\mathbf{g}(\mathbf{r}(t))$?

Comment: @JDoeDoe That's actually a point that user kccu addresses which I've noticed I've missed. If you just want to think of the force at any or all point say $F(\mathbf{r})$. That could be a particular point $\mathbf{r}$ or just the usual function notation. On the other hand if you want to consider the force a particle feels as it moves around in the force field, then if the particle traces a curve $\mathbf{r}(t)$ then at a particular time $t$ it feels a force $F(\mathbf{r}(t))$ at the point $\mathbf{r}(t)$.

Comment: @JDoeDoe I know I'm calling $t$ time but it does help the intuition to call the parameter that parametrises the curve *time*. For example even in differential geometry they call $\dot{\mathbf{r}}(t)$ velocity, in as much as they call its length speed. I mean I suppose if you wanted to consider force on a surface you could have $x(u,v)$ and same for $y,z$ and then have $F(x,y,z)$ then, but it wouldn't be $F(\mathbf{r)}$.

Answer (score 1):

A position vector of a point is the vector pointing from the origin to that point. If the point is fixed, then the position vector has no argument. However, if the point is moving with time, then the position vector depends on a time parameter. In this case we have a parametrization $\textbf{r}(t)$.

A vector field $\textbf{F}$ is typically defined on the entire plan $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $3$-space $\mathbb{R}^3$, so would be of the form $\textbf{F}(x,y)$ or $\textbf{F}(x,y,z)$.

If you have a parametrization $\textbf{r}(t)$ that outputs a vector for every time $t$, then (provided the number of coordinates matches), you could plug that in to a vector field. That is, if $\textbf{r}(t)=(x(t),y(t),z(t))$ and you have a vector field $\textbf{F}(x,y,z)$, then $\textbf{F}(\textbf{r}(t))=F(x(t),y(t),z(t))$. In this case you're only looking at the vector field along the path $\textbf{r}(t)$.

Comment: Thank you! It's confusing for a beginner when the argument is not stated explicit. For instance, in Maxwell's equations, the electric field is just denoted $\mathbf{E}$. I interpt it as $\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r},t)=\mathbf{E}(x,y,z,t)$, a vector field of four variables. But in this context, does it make sense that $\mathbf{E}(x(t),y(t),z(t),t)$? 

However, in a different context, could we have a different argument for the position vector, say $u$, so $\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r}(u),t)=\mathbf{E}(x(u),y(u),z(u),t)$? Confusing =/

Comment: That depends on whether you want the argument $\textbf{r}$ to be anything you want or whether you want it to only be points on a specific curve $\textbf{r}(t)$. When you write $\textbf{E}(x,y,z,t)$, you're saying you can plug in any point $(x,y,z)$. If you write $\textbf{E}(x(t),y(t),z(t),t)$ then you're asking about the electrical field at time $t$ at the point $(x(t),y(t),z(t))$, which is some point on a curve being traced out in time.

Comment: If you have $\textbf{r}(u)$ instead, then you're just saying that the time on the curve and the time you plug into $\textbf{E}$ don't necessarily have to be the same. But you're still only considering $(x,y,z)$ lying on the particular curve $\textbf{r}(u)$.